# Error while comparing two cells from a dataframe. "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" is the error i get

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I was trying to return a dataframe of all the results who's 'high' value of the present day breaches after given number of days. and also return after how many days did it breach its 'high' value. but i get this error now.

```py
instruments = df['instrumnet'].unique()
buy_df = pd.DataFrame()
wait_days = [1,2]
for i in instruments:
    stock_data = new_df.loc[df['instrumnet'] == i]
    stock_data.reset_index()
    for j in range(1,len(stock_data.axes[0])):         
        if ((stock_data['emb_flag'].iloc[j] == 1) & (stock_data['emb_flag'].iloc[j-1] == 0)):
            for k in wait_days:
                if ((stock_data['high'].iloc[j])<(stock_data['high'].iloc[j+k])):
                    buy_df = buy_df.append(stock_data.iloc[j])
                    buy_df['wait_time'] = k
```

Comment: Please include the error message as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.